# How to proxy two api's in package.json when two different backend languanges are used?

Tags: reactjs, server, proxy, package.json

I am trying to proxy two API endpoints from two different backend languages [Node.js, and SpringBoot] in my react app

I was hoping to see if there is a way to proxy the node.js server along with my server on the spring application in the package.json file

this is my current package.json file with proxy

`"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"`

please let me know how I can proxy two api's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your idea with creating a file called `setupProxy.js` inside the src folder.

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
      app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' 
       }));
      app.use(proxy('/api2', {target: 'http://localhost:6000/'}));
 };
```

Comment: Thank you so and just to clarify if I was to all the localhost 5000 it would be http://localhost:5000/api ?

Comment: Yes Jaffer Syed you can do it. For that please refer https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/master/README.md#example